# Calling methods from other methods in the same class

Tags: java

I am trying to call a method from another method in the same class, for example when the "enterValues" method is finished, I want it to go back to the main menu. Can someone please explain how I can do this? I am also a bit confused on the use of objects here, am I right in thinking I need to create an object in every method like I have done here, in order to call other methods?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Conversion {

    int value;

    public void mainMenu() {
        int menuChoice;

        Scanner menuScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Conversion mainMenu = new Conversion();

        System.out.println("1. Enter values and type -1 to stop");
        System.out.println("2. Euros");
        System.out.println("3. Dollars");
        System.out.println("4. Yen");
        System.out.println("5. Rupees");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");


        while (!menuScan.hasNextInt() || (menuChoice = menuScan.nextInt()) > 6) {
            menuScan.nextLine();
            System.err.println("Please enter a valid menu option 1 - 6: "); 
        }


        switch (menuChoice) {
        case 1:

            mainMenu.enterValues();

        case 2:

        }


    }

    public void enterValues() {

        Conversion enterValues = new Conversion();

        Scanner valueScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter value to convert: ");
        value = valueScan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value entered. Returning to main menu.");

        valueScan.close();

        enterValues.mainMenu();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Conversion main = new Conversion();

        main.mainMenu();

    }

}
```

Comment: there is a goto statement in Java. you have to be cautious when you are using it.

Comment: Be care to close the case x:..with break;

Comment: When the method finish its work, it will automatically return to `mainMenu()`, there is no need to call from here.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside a **non-static** method, you already are in an instance of your Class, so no need to create another instance.

Also, when you are in an instance of a class, you just call other methods directly, like `mainMenu();`

I modified your code a bit to reflect this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Conversion {

    int value;

    public void mainMenu() {
        int menuChoice;

        Scanner menuScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("1. Enter values and type -1 to stop");
        System.out.println("2. Euros");
        System.out.println("3. Dollars");
        System.out.println("4. Yen");
        System.out.println("5. Rupees");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");


        while (!menuScan.hasNextInt() || (menuChoice = menuScan.nextInt()) > 6) {
            menuScan.nextLine();
            System.err.println("Please enter a valid menu option 1 - 6: "); 
        }


        switch (menuChoice) {
        case 1:

            enterValues();

        case 2:

        }


    }

    public void enterValues() {


        Scanner valueScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter value to convert: ");
        value = valueScan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value entered. Returning to main menu.");

        valueScan.close();

        mainMenu();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Conversion main = new Conversion();

        main.mainMenu();

    }

}
```

Comment: This will lead to a stack overflow: mainMenu() calling enterValues() which calls mainMenu() again...

Comment: Both methods wait for user entry, and I assume that the future "case 6:" is supposed to exit the application.

Answer (score 0):

You must not create a new object every time you call a method. Within a class you can call any method you want.

If you finish one method, you continue where you called it. So in order to keep the main menu open you would have to use a loop or something similar.

The call itself is nothing more than:

```
mainMenu();
```

respectively

```
enterValues();
```

without creating a new `Conversion`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to *call* `mainMenu` from `enterValues`, you want to *return* to it.

Make a "forever" loop inside `mainMenu`, and add an exit condition with a `break`. This way simply returning from `enterValues` or any other method inside `mainMenu` would bring you back to printing main menu and asking what else you wish to do:

```
public void mainMenu() {
    mainLoop: while (true) {
        int menuChoice;

        Scanner menuScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Conversion mainMenu = new Conversion();

        System.out.println("1. Enter values and type -1 to stop");
        System.out.println("2. Euros");
        System.out.println("3. Dollars");
        System.out.println("4. Yen");
        System.out.println("5. Rupees");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");

        while (!menuScan.hasNextInt() || (menuChoice = menuScan.nextInt()) > 6) {
            menuScan.nextLine();
            System.err.println("Please enter a valid menu option 1 - 6: "); 
        }

        switch (menuChoice) {
        case 1:
            mainMenu.enterValues();
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 6:
            break mainLoop;
        }
    }
}
```